# Pivot table not showing row total Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tested the following codes and set `margins` to be true. However, the result only shows sum of each column but not sum of each row. How to do that, please?

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a1', 1, 1, 11],
     ['a1', 2, 3, 12],
     ['a1', 3, 5, 13],
     ['a2', 4, 7, 14],
     ['a2', 5, 9, 15],
     ['b',  6, 2, 16],
     ['c',  7, 4, 17]],
    columns=['ID1', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']
)

test.pivot_table(values=['Value1'] + ['Value2'], index=['ID1'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True)
      Value1    Value2
ID1     
a1         6         9
a2         9        16
b          6         2
c          7         4
All       28        31
```

Comment: Or just chain the above with `assign(All=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))`.

Comment: @QuangHoang What do you mean by chain...

Comment: `test.pivot_table(...).assign(...)`